# Clipping a layout to the boundary of a polygon

Tags: qgis, layouts

[image: Currently what the layout looks like]

I am trying to clip the layout in QGIS 3.22 to the polygon with the yellow dashed line, is this even possible and if so how. Can you format a map layout so that it is not a rectangle and is a particular shape of a polygon in a map?

Comment: The most straightforward way is probably to use the *Inverted Polygons* symbology type on your polygon layer.

Comment: Perfect! That worked brilliantly thank you